# Can't print out date in sys log when running a service using upstart script

Tags: bash, date, upstart

I am setting up Linux service using upstart script:

```
description "AAE client app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

env PATH=/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/bin
env PROGRAM_NAME="aae"
env USERNAME="ec2-user"

# Main script to be run
script
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Ready to run..." >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log

    export HOME="/home/ec2-user"
    echo $$ > /var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid

    cd /home/ec2-user/aae_client
    exec python -m app.run >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

Inside the `script` block, I tried to print out the date time using `date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ` before running the actual application. However every time I start the service, the date time does not print. In the sys log, I got

```
[] (sys) Ready to run...
```

If I run the exact `echo` command in command line, I got the correct date time

```
 echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Ready to run..."
```

Why can't I print out the date time in sys log using upstart script?

Comment: Is it possible that the `date` command doesn't understand `-u`? Have you tried running that `echo` command on the system?

Comment: Like I said I ran the whole command in command line `echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Ready to run..."` which prints out date perfectly. But in the script, even if I just have `date` alone without any of the formatting stuff and the `-u`, it still does not print out anything